# Can't align buttons programmatically

Tags: java, android

This is my first foray into the Android world and I'm having trouble aligning buttons via code. They just stay stacked on top of each other no matter which Param I set (BELOW, RIGHT_OF, etc.).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                             android:id="@+id/screen2Layout"
                             android:orientation="vertical"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondScreenActivity.java:

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "SecondScreenActivity";
private MjpegView mv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    addContentView(mv, relativeLayoutParams);

    Button zoomIn = new Button(this);
    zoomIn.setText("Zoom In");
    zoomIn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    zoomIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    int zoomInID = View.generateViewId();
    zoomIn.setId(zoomInID);
    this.addContentView(zoomIn, relativeLayoutParams);

    Button zoomOut = new Button(this);
    zoomOut.setText("Zoom Out");
    zoomOut.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    zoomOut.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    int zoomOutID = View.generateViewId();
    zoomIn.setId(zoomOutID);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomOutParam = relativeLayoutParams;
    zoomOutParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, zoomInID);
    this.addContentView(zoomOut, zoomOutParam);
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `this.addContentView` is doing but it seems you use the same `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instance for different views. Each view must get their own instance.

Comment: this.addContentView adds the button to the current view.

Comment: I tried giving each button its own instance of LayoutParams but it still gives the same behavior.

Comment: whats the type of `this`? Does it extend `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple layout why don't you just use a LinearLayout with orientation set to 
horizontal.

Also, you could just lay them out in a relative layout xml and then access them to make any
changes you want. findViewById( ). This is way more traditional and makes it a lot easier to 
do cosmetic layout changes down the road.

I don't see anything here that would require you to do this programatically.

Comment: The reason I feel like I need to do this programmatically is because in the MjpegView class the Surfaceholder overwrites anything that is put in the screen2.xml and I can't figure out how to get around that. So programmatically I can call elements in the correct order to get them all drawn on screen. However, I do kind of like your idea about locking the screen into landscape (gotta figure out how to do that).